# Using RK4 on the van der Pol oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

The van der Pol oscillator is modeled by

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + \mu(y^2 - 1) \frac{dy}{dt} + y = 0$$

This can be written as a system of first order equations, 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dot x\\ \dot y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \mu(1-y^2)x - y\\ x\end{pmatrix},
$$

where $x := \dot y$. Consider the case where $y(0) = 0$ and $x(0) = a$, where $a$ is some real number. A numerical approximation for the solution can be obtained using the RK4 method. I have two questions:

1. How do you find the region of stability for the RK4 method?
2. How can you verify RK4 is 4th order accurate? Surely you would need to know the true solution in order to verify this?

Comment: Did you actually implement RK4 or at least apply some RK4 implementation with fixed step size to  this problem and play around with varying the parameters? What are your observation, what is puzzling to you?

Comment: Upon implementing RK4 I found that RK4 is conditionally stable; the time step must be sufficiently small to get a good approximation to the solution. What I want to know is the actual analysis of finding the region of stability.

Comment: You should also have found that there is a lower bound for the useful step sizes (due to the limits of finite binary formats). There is one region of stability for RK4, defined as in my answer, and the promise that discretization errors and floating point noise are not magnified along the integration if all $z=\lambda h$ fall inside that region for all $\lambda$ eigenvalues of the Jacobian in all points of the trajectory.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand\rx{\mathfrak{x}}\newcommand\ru{\mathfrak{u}}\newcommand\mA{\mathfrak{A}}$

1. ) For the definition of the most common stability properties one refers to the properties of solutions of linear systems of ODE. Apply the RK4 method to some linear system $\ru'=\mA\ru$ (for instance the linearization of a non-linear ODE system around a fixed point). You should get exactly the first 5 terms (up to degree 4) of the exponential series.

   > The **stability condition** is that this propagator has to be non-expanding if the spectrum of $\mA$ is contained in the negative half-plane of the complex plane. On the level of singular eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $z=λh$ with step size $h$ this means that $z$ is in the **stability region** if  $$|1+z+z^2/2+z^3/6+z^4/24|\le1.$$

   The half-circle with $\Im(z)\le 0$, $|z|\le 2.5$ is contained in that set.

   If $L$ is a *Lipschitz constant* (or $L=\|\mA\|$), then this gives a bound $h<2.5/L$. At the upper bound the numerical solution is merely not totally wrong, for a useful solution one needs a much smaller step size, $Lh\in[10^{-3},10^{-1}]$. Step sizes much smaller than that lead to an accumulation of floating point errors that dominate the method error.

   See [Maximum timestep for RK4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1210698/115115) for visualizations of the stability region and the effect of too small or too large step sizes.
2. ) There are two readily available strategies to explore the error picture of a numerical ODE solver.

   - One proceeds to compute a series of results over a series of doubled step sizes $Lh=(1,2,4,8)·10^{-2}$. Compare these to the expected formula $y_h=y^*+C·h^4+O(h^5)$, that is, apply **Richardson extrapolation** to compute values for $C$ and $y^*$ and check if they are stable over all the doublings.
   - Another strategy uses **MMS** (manufactured solutions). Here one would fix some nice function $p$ and consider the equation
     $$
     y''+μ(y^2−1)y'+y=p''+μ(p^2−1)p'+p, ~~~y(0)=p(0),~~y'(0)=p'(0),
     $$
     for instance $p(t)=2\sin(t)$ or with the next perturbation term added. Then $p$ is the exact solution that the numerical solution can be compared against.
   - If you want to actually prove the order, that is, verify the **order conditions**, read up on **Butcher trees**, for instance on Butcher's homepage https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/. Or read the original derivation of the low order Runge-Kutta methods in W. Kutta (1901) https://archive.org/details/zeitschriftfrma12runggoog/page/n449

Comment: Why must we use $y' = AY$? What about the $x'$ equation? Surely the region of stability for the van der Pol equation is not the same as the region of stability for $y' = AY$?

Comment: The stability is always for the linearized system, and if that is diagonalized one is led to the equation $y'=\lambda y$. There is only one region of stability for RK4, and then there are the eigenvalues of the Jacobian of the system that determine the bounds on the step size. Usually, a Lipschitz constant is a sufficient replacement for the spectral radius.